# How can I convert a 4x4 transformation matrix from one coordinate system to another using Python?

Tags: python, math, matrix, linear-algebra, pybullet

I am trying to convert a transformation matrix from one coordinate system to another. The first coordinate system looks like this in a pybullet simulation:

[image: pybullet simulation]

I'm assuming this coordinate system would be:

- X = Forward
- Y = Away From Camera
- Z = Up

Though I'm not sure about the orientation of the XY plane.

The second coordinate system looks like this:

[image]

I'm assuming this coordinate system would be:

- X = Forward
- Y= Up
- Z = Toward The Camera

Though I'm not sure about the orientation of the XZ plane.

The coordinate conversion should then be something like this:

(X,Y,Z)->(X,-Z,Y)

This is the following code I wrote to achieve the transformation:

```py
def transform_matrix(self,transformation_matrix):
    #X maps to X (1,0,0)
    #Y maps to -Z (0,0,-1)
    #Z maps to -Y (0,-1,0)
        

    C = np.matrix([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, -1,0],
        [0, -1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]])

    C_prime = np.transpose(C)

    return C @ transformation_matrix @ C_prime
```

Which I derived from [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203073/how-to-convert-a-4x4-matrix-transformation-to-another-coordinate-system)

This code, however, isn't working. I'm not sure if it's because the code itself is incorrect, or if my mapping is incorrect. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: why not just swaping the columns?

Comment: @PabloC do you mean making the y column equal to the -z column? I've tried that as well.

Comment: Why does the comment say Y maps to -Z? In the pictures both Y and Z go up?

Comment: I took the same logic that was specified in the link I provided, but Y maps to -Z because in the original coordinate system, Y goes away from the camera; whereas, Z goes towards the camera

Answer (score 1):

So @JamesParrott was correct in that you do have a mathematical error. The concept that you are missing is not that you are mapping coordinates simply applying a sign change or such. I think we need more  context here. Are you applying a rotation matrix (as link indicated)

Also the link you provided is a discussion around a 4D rotation matrix (x,y,z,w) - I am guessing your application would be a 3x3 Matrix.

Furthermore, I am gonna link here - don't kill this post, haha. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

That link is on Rotation Matrices - a standard mathematical concept you can find any number of links on.

If you are simply wanting to map the space (X,Y,Z) to (X, -Z, -Y), then your matrix should be
[[1 0 0], [0, 0, -1], [0, -1, 0]]

To understand why this works, do the following matrix multiplication (I recommend using Wolfram Alpha for simple understandings like this)

[image: Transformation]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a simple sign error?  In the link, the middle two non-zero entries are +1 and -1.  Your matrix has both equal to -1.

[4x4 matrix from the link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg8qC.png)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear with the link. The only portion I derived from the link is the equation M_{new} = C * M * C^-1, which yields the transformation matrix in the new coordinate space. My coordinate systems are not the same from the link, however.

Comment: Ah sorry.  Which error are you getting, and what transformation_matrix are you calling it with?

Comment: So some answers I need help with are, is my transform_matrix function mathematically correct in terms of changing a transformation matrix from one coordinate system to another? Additionally, how should I interpret the pictures of the coordinate systems I provided? I don't know how to tell what is left, right, forward, or back.

Comment: The equation ought to be C^-1 M C, but it should make no difference in your case as your C matrix satisfies C = C' = C^-1  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis#Endomorphisms